# Scrapy Shell gets Killed

Tags: python, scrapy

I used the scrapy shell a few times today without problem.  Then I ran a spider, the spider was killed. Now I can't even start the shell, it gets killed after about 10 seconds.  I rebooted several times...didn't solve the problem.  I was able to start django in another virtualenv.  Memory resources look fine. Anybody have any insight into this mystery?  I did see the following in /var/log/kern.log

```
scrapy invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24280ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
scrapy cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
```

Thank you.

**Edit/Update:**

Also saw this:

```
Out of memory: Kill process 13170 (scrapy) score 803 or sacrifice child
```

Comment: Also saw this:  Out of memory: Kill process 13170 (scrapy) score 803 or sacrifice child

Comment: I increased the memory on my VM to 2GB, up from 1GB, and it's working now.  Scrapy shell is consuming about 1GB of memory.